# RestKit: POST error (Loaded an unprocessable error response (400))

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rest, restkit

I've had this problem the whole day. I'm working with RestKit and I've successfully made a GET request and mapped all the information into an object. Below is a code snippet where I make a GET request followed by a POST request (for testing). I post the object I just received to the server again. But! My POST request fails. I tried testing the REST API with the chrome plugin Postman which confirms the REST API is working correct. Below is the code which makes a GET and POST request:

```
- (void)loadSample
{
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"sampling/243570" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        Sample *obj = [mappingResult.array firstObject];
        [[SampleList sharedInstance] addSample:obj];
        [self.tableView reloadData];


        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:obj path:@"sampling" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            NSLog(@"POST: Success");
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"POST: Failure");
        }];

    } failure:nil];
}
```

I get the following debugging message when trying to post:

> restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:208 POST 'https://XXXX.dk/api/sampling' (400 Bad Request / 0 objects) [request=0.0258s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0320s]:
>   error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>       "application/json"
>   )}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0x10a81f5d0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://XXXX.dk/api/sampling, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey= { URL: https://XXXX.dk/api/sampling }, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= { URL: https://XXXX.dk/api/sampling } { status code: 400, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
>       "Content-Length" = 0;
>       Date = "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 17:21:57 GMT";
>       Expires = "-1";
>       Pragma = "no-cache";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
>       "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
>   } }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
>       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>       "application/json"
>   )}, got text/plain}
>   response.body=

So I added the following line in the method: configureRestKit (listed below)

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];
```

and got the following debugging message for my POST request. Been look at it the whole day, and can't see what I'm during wrong because it handles my GET request perfect (So I don't think my mappings is incorrect):

> 2014-07-24 18:46:21.199 XXXX[1492:60b] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:148 POST 'https://XXXX.dk/api/sampling':
>
> request.headers={
>       "Accept-Language" = "da;q=1, en;q=0.9, fr;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, zh-Hans;q=0.6, zh-Hant;q=0.5";
>       Authorization = XXXX.dk;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json";
>       "User-Agent" = "XXXX/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 7.1; Scale/2.00)";
>   }
>
> request.body=(null)
>
> 2014-07-24 18:46:21.234 XXXX.dk[1492:f03] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:208 POST 'https://XXXX.dk/api/sampling' (400 Bad Request / 0 objects) [request=0.0343s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0405s]:
>   error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Loaded an unprocessable error response (400)" UserInfo=0x10a6b5780 {NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable error response (400), NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://XXXX.dk/api/sampling}
>   response.body=

The configuration I use for RestKit is listed below:

```
- (void)configureRestKit
{    
    // initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://XXXX.dk/api/"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];


    // initialize RestKit
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
    [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];

    // register mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider sampleMapping]
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}
```

[MappingProvider sampleMapping] is returns the following:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *) sampleMapping {
   RKObjectMapping *sampleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Sample class]];
   [sampleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"SampleId":        @"sampleId",
                                                       @"Type":            @"type",
                                                       @"Scope":           @"scope",
                                                       @"SamplingMethod":  @"samplingMethod"
                                                       }];

   [sampleMapping addPropertyMapping:[MappingProvider fieldAnalysisMapping]];
   [sampleMapping addPropertyMapping:[MappingProvider sampleDataMapping]];
   [sampleMapping addPropertyMapping:[MappingProvider laboratoryAnalysisMapping]];

   return sampleMapping;
```

}

Comment: Do you have a request descriptor?

Comment: Nope - I read that the framework would automatic inverse RKResponseDescriptor for mapping it back to JSON? I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Where did you read that? It isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution thanks to Wain

I tried to implement a RKRequestDescriptor. I added the following code:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[[MappingProvider sampleMapping] inverseMapping] objectClass:[Sample class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```